# How do I save the URL that was requested and forward to it after the user went through the captive portal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies, captiveportal

I have the following code:

```
public class CookieCheckMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CookieCheckMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if(httpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] == null && httpContext.Request.Path != "/WhereIShouldGo")
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("/WhereIShouldGo");
        }
        await _next(httpContext); // calling next middleware

    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class CookieCheckMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCookieCheckMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CookieCheckMiddleware>();
    }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseCookieCheckMiddleware();

    ...
}
```

It basically redirects to the captive portal if no cookie is set. Now I need to up a level - I need to somehow save the httpContext.Request.Path and forward to it RIGHT AFTER the user accepted the cookies. So setting a cookie beforehand is not an option, since the user hasn't accepted it yet... How could I accomplish that?

Comment: You create an API method to get the current URL, and then the page will forward the obtained URL to the captive portal after accepting the cookie, right?

Comment: @Chaodeng yes, that's how it should basically work. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was giving the request URL via the redirect like this:
`httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Cookies?q="+ httpContext.Request.Path);`
and then via JavaScript getting the GET parameter and redirecting after clicking on the button.

Case closed :-)

Comment: This way also no Referer have to be taken, which are nowadays not that well implemented as I've and others noticed.